# How to get TFS2012 to include a changeset in the build that was checked in during the build process?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have a TFS 2012 build.

Within the build I have a custom code activity.  This code activity is a versioning activity and it simply goes into Source Control and edits an XML file then checks it back into source control.

The issue is that I want this changeset to be included within the `Associated Changesets` of the build, but can't seem to get this to work.

**Does anyone know where in the build lifecycle I can put this custom code activity so that it is included?**

I know there is an `associatedChangesets` variable floating around, could I just manually add it to that collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly where the cut off is, but I have moved my custom activity around and if I put it **before** `If CreateLabel` it seems to work as expected.

I am using the `DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml` as my starting point.